# How to include a css file in pugjs template

Tags: node.js, pug, templating, templating-engine, pugjs

I'm using pugjs for my project.I was unable to load a css file in the pug template. I'm using the following code

index.pug

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="views/styles/products.css", type="text/css")
```

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP5H3.png)

Comment: That's the right syntax, make sure the path is right.

Comment: Mr.Paul can u please verify my project structure and tell its right or wrong

Comment: I think you don't tell to your node.js app folder `/views` serving "static" files. I recommand you to add a folder `/public`, place all your static files here and tell in your server.js this folder serving static file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is not going to serve anything that you don't give permission to. You have to give permission by using express.static middleware.

Put your Static files in a folder then use the express.static middleware like  this-

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

For more details refer to https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

My directory setup looks something like this:

```
    .
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.pug
    ├── index.pug
```

And in the index.pug, we have to use:

```
 html
      head
        title=homepage
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/views/dashboard/dashboard.css')
      body
```

And in app.js add this line of code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```